# Resonant Cavity Visualization

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

I am visualizing resonant cavity modes in a rectangular box using python but its been a long time since I looked at resonant cavities so would like a second opinion.  The package can be found [here](https://github.com/Rhys314/Resonant_Cavity) for those who want to play with it.  At the moment only TE modes are available.  The equations are from Jackson 3rd Ed [section 8.7, p. 369, equations (8.77)]

$$
\textbf{E}_t=-\frac{i\omega\mu}{\gamma^2}\sin\left(\frac{p\pi z}{c}\right)\hat{\textbf{z}}\times\nabla_t\psi
$$
$$
\textbf{H}_t=\frac{p\pi}{c\gamma^2}\cos\left(\frac{p\pi z}{c}\right)\nabla_t\psi
$$

My python package produces some quiver plots show the imaginary E-field and the real H-field, which I am unsure about.  For the imaginary part of the E-field of a  TE10 mode I get parallel field lines but for the H-field there is variation in the field over two planes[image: "TE10 Real Magnetic Field"]
I expected the H-field to be have a rotational field in one plane and that's it, not to also have what looks like a parabolic dependency in the plane coming out of the screen.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

In a TE mode, there is a non-vanishing component of the magnetic field, given by $\psi$, along a cavity or a waveguide, which is perpendicular to the plane coming out of the screen. In a rectangular cavity, that component is sinusoidal with discrete modes as well, due to standing waves being created between the boundaries of the cavity.

In fact this component is responsible for energy loss across the walls of the cavity and can be an important design consideration.